# BERT word embeddings

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I'm trying to use BERT in a static word embeddings kind of way to compare to Word2Vec and show the differences and how BERT is not really meant to be used in a contextless manner.

This is how (based on many blogsposts and tutorials) I am attempting to do that

```
def get_hidden_states(encoded, model, layers):
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(**encoded)

    states = output.hidden_states

    # Stack final 4 layers
    output = torch.stack([states[i] for i in layers]).sum(0).squeeze() ## shape torch.Size([5, 768])

    return output.mean(dim=0) ##average 
 
def get_word_vector(sent, tokenizer, model, layers):
    encoded = tokenizer.encode_plus(sent, return_tensors="pt")

##{'input_ids': tensor([[ 101, 9712, 4774, 3408,  102]]), 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}

    return get_hidden_states(encoded, model, layers)

word = "embeddings"
layers = [-4, -3, -2, -1]

tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased", output_hidden_states=True)

word_embed = get_word_vector(word, tokenizer, model, layers) ## shape torch.Size([768])
```

My main question is, do I exclude the CLS and SEP embeddings when I average the subtokens to get a whole word representation? Or should these be theoretically included?

Comment: [CLS] and [SEP] are special tokens that are not included in any word. Unless you want to keep the information that a word is the first of the sentence but probably not

Answer (score 0):

you can just add a add_special_tokens paramater to add or remove special tokens

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pertrained('bert-base-uncased')

sentence = 'test 1 2 3'

features = tokenizer(
   sentence, padding='do_not_pad', add_special_tokens=False, return_tensors='pt'
)
```